# WebStorm/PhpStorm not loading a font

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

Reinstalling the font and the software including its' folders didn't help to resolve the issue.

Why does the software not display the font? I would assume it caches it some place on the hard drive.

[image]

Comment: have you tried the `file --> clear caches and restart` link?

Comment: Des the font work on other programs on your computer? is the font properly installed?

Comment: Maybe PhpStorm simply doesn't like crappy fonts. Standards need to be maintained!

Comment: Clearing the caches didn't work out. Notepad++ works with each of the family font well. WebStorm worked with Source Code Pro regular well till I did something.

Comment: Try re-downloading the font from some other source perhaps. On related note: 1) https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-168744 2) https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-96738

Comment: Thanks. I removed all the Source Code Pro fonts now the IDE won't display any of the font family even after I installed the Regular one. It displayed various symbols in the font list in place of the deleted fonts before.